# Google maps doesn't work in one activity but works in another

Tags: android, google-maps

I made an app that tracks a users location and draws a polyline on a google map fragment to show their path. I store the latlng information in my SQLite database so that I can draw the path again in another activity to show the user their path.

My issue is that google maps works fine in the activity where I am tracking the location, however the google map fragment in the viewing activity is blank, *but it still shows the markers*. I have already tried making a new API key, which didn't work. Searching for this issue on google, I can only find people who can't get a single map fragment working and the issue is usually the API key. I've already made sure that the latlng points are correct aswell.

The class where the map fragment isn't working:

```
package com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge;

public class ViewingActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private List<LatLng> points;
Polyline line;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewing);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map2);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    points = PolyUtil.decode(bundle.getString("LOCATIONS"));

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //mMap.clear();
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    options.addAll(points);

    LatLng start = new LatLng(points.get(0).latitude, points.get(0).longitude);
    LatLng end = new LatLng(points.get(points.size() - 1).latitude, points.get(points.size() - 1).latitude);

    Marker startMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Start Position").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    startMarker.setPosition(start);

    Marker endMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("End Position").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    endMarker.setPosition(end);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(end, 15));
    Log.d("g53mdp", "Camera Moved");

    line = mMap.addPolyline(options);
}
```

}

It's XML:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map2"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge.ViewingActivity" />
```

My Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />

    <provider
        android:name=".ExerciseProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge.ExerciseProvider" />

    <service
        android:name=".TrackingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name=".ListActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FilterActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_viewing"></activity>
</application>
```

----EDIT----
Here is the logcat from when the viewing activity is started:

```
12-28 01:53:01.347 21376-21376/com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 10260000
12-28 01:53:01.352 21376-21376/com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11509470
12-28 01:53:01.666 21376-21425/com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-28 01:53:01.666 21376-21425/com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe86eb840, error=EGL_SUCCESS

                                                                            [ 12-28 01:53:01.676 21376:21927 D/         ]
                                                                            HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd6d55950, tid 21927
12-28 01:53:01.718 21376-21376/com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge D/g53mdp: Camera Moved
12-28 01:53:03.618 21376-21929/com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
12-28 01:53:06.546 21376-21929/com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
12-28 01:53:06.546 21376-21929/com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
12-28 01:53:06.555 21376-21929/com.example.bocks.mdplab4merge W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000001/n/x86
```

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of empty map with markers marked

Comment: @Naz141, [here](https://imgur.com/fWeepej) Its a link to imgur, i don't think I can upload images here.

Comment: You can check the logs, if there is a problem regarding maps, it will be logged in the logcat.

Comment: @SripadRaj, I've attached the logcat. As far as I can tell, there is no error...